# Is it possible to splice an item from an array using a 'for of' loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, for-of-loop

I've been able to figure out splicing using a 'for' loop and a 'for in' loop, but not a 'for of' loop.  Is it possible?  Here's my starting code... any ideas what I can change to make it work?

```
let array = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
function remove( letter ){
    for( let item of array ){
        if( item === letter ){
            parkedCars.splice ( item, 1 );
        }
    }
}
remove( 'b' );
console.log( array );
```

Comment: Both arguments to `.splice` need to be indexes. `item` isn’t an index. Without one, you can’t reliably make it work.

Comment: Try describing what you would like to happen, there may be a better solution than forEach and splice.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `for...of` loop on `Array.prototype.entries()` and then check value and remove item by index using `splice()`.

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function remove(arr, letter) {
  for (let [index, item] of arr.entries()) {
    if (item === letter) arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
remove(array, 'b');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Admittedly, that is *the way*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can track the index yourself, it's not very pretty though.

```
let index = 0;
for( let item of array ){
    if( item === letter ){
        parkedCars.splice ( index, 1 );
    }
    index++;
}
```